# Is there a way to quickly update a column formula?

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, you can double click the corner handle of a cell to copy-down a formula in blank cells underneath it as far down as there are non-blank cells in the adjacent left column.

So let's say I've done that, but now I need to change the formula. Now if I try to double-click again, it doesn't work because the cells below aren't empty. I have to grab the handle and manually drag it to the bottom of the column. Sometimes I have thousands of rows and it gets pretty annoying.

I'm fairly certain Excel doesn't have this problem, it will update existing formulas when you double click.

Am I missing a setting somewhere? Is there a hotkey for this, or an add-on, a script, a clever trick I could use?

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy the formula
2. Select everything below your cell (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> on mac)
3. Paste

Answer (score 0):

You must have used ARRAYFORMULA for your formula to fill the area you need. And then you can change the formula without further action.